# ReactJS Check if Email exists in an external URL API

Tags: reactjs

I'm very new to ReactJS and trying to build a form that fetches data from an external api. My issue is I'm not sure how to go about validating if the email already exists in the api. My form works great for creating new clients but hoping you could assist in how to check if the email exists and if so, just return a message and not submit the form?

here is my code thus far;

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [homeClubId, sethomeClubId] = useState("1");
  const [firstName, setfirstName] = useState("");
  const [lastName, setlastName] = useState("");
  const [phoneNumber, setphoneNumber] = useState("");
  const [email, setemail] = useState("");
  const [street, setstreet] = useState("");
  const [postalCode, setpostalCode] = useState("");
  const [cityName, setcityName] = useState("");
  const [stateId, setstateId] = useState("");
  const [countrySymbol, setcountrySymbol] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  let handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let res = await fetch("https://localhost:3000/addGuest",{
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          'x-client-ID': 'ID', 
          'x-client-Secret': 'secret'
      },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          "homeClubId": 1,
            "parentMemberId": null,
            "employeeConsultantId": null,
            "recommendedByMemberId": null,
            "recommendedByReferralCode": null,
            "personalData": {
              "firstName": "null",
              "lastName": "TEST",
              "birthDate": null,
              "sex": "other",
              "phoneNumber": "0486991394",
              "email": "apitest557@test2.com",
              "citizenshipCountrySymbol": null,
              "personalId": null,
              "documentTypeId": null,
              "documentNumber": null
            },
            "addressData": {
              "street": null,
              "additionalAddressLine": null,
              "postalCode": null,
              "cityId": null,
              "cityName": null,
              "stateId": null,
              "countrySymbol": "AU"
            },
            "agreements": [
              {
                "agreementId": 3,
                "agreementAnswer": true
              },
              {
                "agreementId": 16,
                "agreementAnswer": true
              },
              {
                "agreementId": 17,
                "agreementAnswer": true
              }
            ]
        }),
      });
      let resJson = await res.json();
      if (res.status === 200) {
        setfirstName("");
        setlastName("");
        setphoneNumber("");
        setemail("");
        setstreet("");
        setpostalCode("");
        setcityName("");
        setstateId("");
        setcountrySymbol("AU");
        sethomeClubId("1");
        setMessage("User created successfully");
        console.log(resJson)
      } else {
        setMessage("Email already exists");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={firstName}
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={(e) => setfirstName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={lastName}
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={(e) => setlastName(e.target.value)}
        />
         <input
          type="text"
          value={phoneNumber}
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={(e) => setphoneNumber(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={email}
          placeholder="Email"
          onChange={(e) => setemail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={street}
          placeholder="Mobile Number"
          onChange={(e) => setstreet(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={postalCode}
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={(e) => setpostalCode(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={cityName}
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={(e) => setcityName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          value={stateId}
          placeholder="Name"
          onChange={(e) => setstateId(e.target.value)}
        />

        <button type="submit">Create</button>

        <div className="message">{message ? <p>{message}</p> : null}</div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What does your API look like? What tech are you using? The provided React code looks good but it does not show how the API works to answer your question about email validation

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @AntoineGagnon, I'm so sorry if i'm wrong in any of this (again, super new to react). the API is in JSON format, and it stores the email under {email}, i'm trying to use axios. 

here is what console log looks like if that helps;

'value
: 
[{firstName: "Ben", secondName: null, lastName: "Smith", homeClubId: 1, isActive: true,…}]
0
: 
{firstName: "Ben", secondName: null, lastName: "Smith", homeClubId: 1, isActive: true,…}
birthdate
: 
"1991-06-12T00:00:00+10:00"
consultantId
: 
3
email
: 
"here@here.com"
firstName
: 
"Ben"'